# Unit test code of web worker

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, web-worker

Taking the example code from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/basic_usage , the following is run by a web worker

```
// in worker.js
onmessage = function(e) {
  console.log('Message received from main script');
  var workerResult = 'Result: ' + (e.data[0] * e.data[1]);
  console.log('Posting message back to main script');
  postMessage(workerResult);
}
```

run by code in an Angular service/factory

```
var myWorker = new Worker("worker.js");
```

I would like to be able to unit test the code in `worker.js`, ideally running it as part of an Angular service/factory (in a separate app running in the web worker?), so I can use the DI system to inject mocks of dependencies, and have the unit test code looking much like the tests for any other service. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way to do this, where the main code run in a web worker is run as part of a separate, manually-bootstrapped, Angular module.

In order to load Angular in a web worker

- The environment needs to be tinkered with/monkey patched/hacked so Angular doesn't throw various exceptions when it loads and bootstraps due to missing `window` and `document` objects
- Angular must then be included via `importScripts`
- Then the module you would like to run must be included via `importScripts`
- Then the module manually bootstrapped.

Example code that does this:

```
// worker.js

// Angular needs a global window object
var window = self;

// Skeleton properties to get Angular to load and bootstrap.
self.history = {};
var document = {
  readyState: 'complete',
  querySelector: function() {},
  createElement: function() {
    return {
      pathname: '',
      setAttribute: function() {}
    }
  }
};

// Load Angular: must be on same domain as this script
importScripts('angular.js');

// Put angular on global scope
angular = window.angular;

// Standard angular module definition
importScripts('worker-app.js');

// No root element seems to work fine
angular.bootstrap(null, ['worker-app']);
```

The code of the Angular module itself can then be very standard: with services/factories defined as desired. In this case, none are needed and I've opted to put the simple code of the example as a `run` callback (I've omitted the `console.log`s from the question).

```
// worker-app.js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var app = angular.module('worker-app', []);

  app.run(function($window) {
    $window.onmessage = function(e) {
      var workerResult = 'Result: ' + (e.data[0] * e.data[1]);
      $window.postMessage(workerResult);
    };
  });

})();
```

This can then be tested using exactly the same tests as if it weren't meant to run in a web worker:

```
// worker-app-spec.js
describe('worker-app', function() {
  'use strict';

  var $window;

  beforeEach(module('worker-app'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$window_) {
    $window = _$window_;
  }));

  beforeEach(function() {
    spyOn($window, 'postMessage');
  })

  it('attaches to $window onmessage', function() {
    var data = [2,3];
    var result = 'Result: ' + (data[0] * data[1]);
    $window.onmessage({data: data});
    expect($window.postMessage).toHaveBeenCalledWith(result);
  });
});
```

I'm not such a fan of hacking the environment to get Angular to load, as it feels very brittle to me, so other answers very welcome! The above code was tested using AngularJS v1.3.7.