# Angular in Web Worker

Tags: angularjs, web-worker

Can you get access to an angular service from a Web Worker? Most ways I see to get access are all through the DOM like:

```
var ServiceName = angular.element(document.body).injector().get('ServiceName');
```

but there isn't a DOM in a Web Worker.

Comment: I don't even think you have acess to angular, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219775/global-variable-in-web-worker

Comment: Are you wanting access to the same in-memory instance of a service that is in the angular app in the page, or would you just like to run the code of the service?

Comment: @MichalCharemza I would just like to run the code from a service. I know you can't share objects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run Angular in a web worker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668430/is-it-possible-to-run-angular-in-a-web-worker)