# importScripts in webworker, ignore reference exceptions

Tags: javascript, import, web-worker

I am trying to import a javascript file in a webworker which contains document references and therefore fails. Is it possible to supress the reference exceptions? I only need a handfull of functions from the javascript file which should not use the document object. Or do I need to rebuild the js library from source excluding everything I won't need.

Cheers,
Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar to load Angular in a web worker, in https://stackoverflow.com/a/27931746/1319998 . My solution was to create dummy versions of the objects in the global scope, with just enough properties and functions so Angular wouldn't throw exceptions when it tried to access them, and then load Angular using `importScripts`.

The code below is what worked for me for Angular, which needed not only `document` , but `window` and `history` as well

```
// In the web worker

// Angular needs a global window object
self.window = self;

// Skeleton properties to get Angular to load and bootstrap.
self.history = {};
self.document = {
  readyState: 'complete',
  querySelector: function() {},
  createElement: function() {
    return {
      pathname: '',
      setAttribute: function() {}
    }
  }
};

// Load Angular: must be on same domain as this script
self.importScripts('angular.js');
```

Comment: Mmm... Interesting. That definitely gives me some ideas. Although the problem is now that the imports chokes now on an implementation.createDocument statement in the script. Might have to look at the skeleton properties in order to fix this. Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: @DennisBauszus Not offhand. I think you might have to put more details in the question (/another question)

Comment: No problem. I accept this as the correct answer and will get back to this in the future.